# Comment controller with table view section header and footer

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uitableview

[image]

How can I achieve this screen with UITableViewCell and UITableViewController. With table section and header. Some ideas to achieve this?? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far?
Your question seems a little broad.

You will need a set of custom UITableViewCell Subclasses, which you design in nibs.

To make the cells seem apart from each other, resize the content size of the Cells, and make the cell background another color.

Create a Segmented Control and add it to the Tableviews HeaderView.

For the FooterView it seems like this is some kind of subclassed Tabbar.
Easiest way to customise it in such a way, would be to create a View, and add buttons to it. Add this View as Subview to your TableViewController.

Comment: I want comment on picture like we do in facebook. And make the cell dynamic height increase or decrease

Comment: Make the height of a cell dynamically by adding constraints to the expanding outlets (eg. the comment label) and calling tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Comment: Do u have any demo project for this in Objective C ?

Comment: http://derpturkey.com/autosize-uitableviewcell-height-programmatically/

Maybe this will guide you in the right direction.

Also see my updated answer for Header and Footer

Answer (score 0):

Have 2 UITableViewCell's one for each type i.e. 1 for showing the image and text and another for showing just the text.

Then in the cellForRowAt delegate method determine which to type to use based off the object you are data binding it to.

Example:

```
public final func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let customObject = customObjects[indexPath.section]

    switch customObject.type {
    case .imageAndText:

        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ImageAndTextCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? ImageAndTextCell {
            cell.customObject = customObject
            return cell
        }
    case .text:

        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TextCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? TextCell {
            cell.customObject = customObject
            return cell
        }
    }

    return UITableViewCell()
}
```